# Vue.js – New routes are always placed on top of current route

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

In my `Vue.js` application I use a navigation drawer on the left side of the screen for navigation purposes. I am using `Vuetify` and `Vue Router`.

**Problem**
After changing my `routes` a lot of my previously routing functionalities got messed up. Whenever a user clicks on an element to navigate to a new site the route get's attached on top of the previous one like this.

Route before a user clicks on a link:

```
http://localhost:8080/organization/:organization_id/planner/events
```

New route after a user clicks on a link:

```
http://localhost:8080/organization/:organization_id/planner/management/contracts
```

**Router**

```
routes: [
    // Login
    {
        path: '/login',
        component: Login,
    },
    // Organization
    {
        path: '/organization',
        component: Organization,
    },
    // Organization Detail Page
    {
        path: '/organization/:organization_id',
        component: OrganizationDetail,
        children: [    
            // Module: Planner
            {
                path: 'planner',
                component: Planner
            },
            // Planner > Events
            {
                path: 'planner/events',
                component: Events
            },
            {
                path: 'planner/events/new',
                component: NewEvent
            },
            {
                path: 'planner/events/details/:event_id',
                component: EventDetails
            },
            // Planner > Calendar
            {
                path: 'planner/calendar',
                component: Calendar
            },
            // Module: Management
            {
                path: 'management',
                component: Management
            },
            // Management > Users
            {
                path: 'management/users',
                component: Events
            },
            {
                path: 'management/users/new',
                component: NewUser
            },
            {
                path: 'management/users/details/:user_id',
                component: UserDetails
            },
            // Planner > Contracts
            {
                path: 'management/contracts',
                component: Contracts
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**NavigationDrawer.vue (updated):**

```
    <template>
  <div id="navigation">
    <nav>
        <v-navigation-drawer
          v-model="drawer"
          :clipped="$vuetify.breakpoint.lgAndUp"
          width="400"
          fixed
          app
        >
          <v-list>
            <template v-for="item in items">
              <v-row
                v-if="item.heading"
                :key="item.heading"
                align="center"
              >
              </v-row>
              <v-list-group
                v-else-if="item.children"
                :key="item.text"
                v-model="item.model"
                append-icon="mdi-chevron-down"
                class="nav"
                link
                router :to="item.route"
              >
                <v-list-item
                  v-for="(child, i) in item.children"
                  :key="i"
                  link
                  router :to="child.route"
                >
                  <v-list-item-action v-if="child.icon">
                    <v-icon>{{ child.icon }}</v-icon>
                  </v-list-item-action>
                  <v-list-item-content>
                    <v-list-item-title>
                      {{ child.text }}
                    </v-list-item-title>
                  </v-list-item-content>
                </v-list-item>
              </v-list-group>
            </template>
          </v-list>
        </v-navigation-drawer>
    
        <v-app-bar
          :clipped-left="$vuetify.breakpoint.lgAndUp"
          app
          dark
        >
          <v-app-bar-nav-icon @click.stop="drawer = !drawer"></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
          
        </v-app-bar>
    </nav>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

  export default {
    name: 'NavigationDrawer',
    el: '#app',

    data: () => ({
      drawer: true,
      menu: false,
      items: [
    {
        text: 'Planner',
        children: [
            { text: 'Events', route:'/organization/' + this.$route.params.organization_id + '/planner/events'},
            { text: 'Calendar', route:'/organization/' + this.$route.params.organization_id + '/planner/calendar'}
        ],
    },
    {
        text: 'Management',
        children: [
            { text: 'Users', route:'/organization/' + this.$route.params.organization_id + '/management/users'},
            { text: 'Contracts', route:'/organization/' + this.$route.params.organization_id + '/management/contracts'}
        ],
    },
]
    }),
    methods: {
      logout() {
        // some awesome stuff
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

*Other routes like (NewUser, NewEvent) are not stored in the navigation drawer and called manually by a button.*

I know that this has something to do with my routes. However those aren't misconfigured because the relations between parent and children are important for displaying the right content and implementing some header informations. The navigation drawer works also the right way. I didn't change anything there.

Also if I use `router.back()` on `NewEvent` or `NewUser` nothing happens. :(

Help is very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The contracts route is a child of the organization detail route, so it will inherit the path of organization detail. It appears to be working as it should.

Comment: @DecadeMoon That's right. The "organization/:organization_id" should always be inherited. But the app also inherits the module page (e.g. "planner" or "management").

Comment: Please show the code for your links?

Comment: @Phil I updated the question with all of the necessary code.

Comment: @mcd can you `route:'/management/users'` change this to `route:'/organization/1/management/users'` or whatever organization_id you are using and check if it working or not...

Comment: @HimanshuBansal That's working, thanks. I store the current organization_id in my vuex store. Is there a way to get this into the route dynamically so I have a structure like this: route:'/organization/' + organization_ID_from_vux + '/management/users' ?

Comment: @mcd Answered ^^ Do let me know if you need more explanation.

Comment: @HimanshuBansal Got it, thanks! Can you add some information on how to embed the {{ $route.params.id }} into the route in the array?

Comment: @mcd Updated the answer for that ^^

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224173/discussion-between-mcd-and-himanshu-bansal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because of

```
{ text: 'Events', route:'/planner/events'},
```

The above route redirects the website to http://localhost:8080/planner/events because of initial forward slash.

Use the `$route.params` to get params from URL like the following.

```
<div>User {{ $route.params.organization_id }}</div>
```

or

```
this.$route.params.organization_id
```

Comment: How do I embed 'this.$route.params.organization_id' in to my array? Output should be the route with the id from the params. But I can't write it just in the String to get the final output.

Comment: @mcd `route:'/organization/' + this.$route.params.organization_id + '/management/users'`  or you can `var organization_ID_from_vux =  this.$route.params.organization_id; route:'/organization/' + organization_ID_from_vux + '/management/users' `

Comment: I've tried exactly that before but it let's my navigation drawer just be blank :(

Comment: @mcd Can you add imports of the file in which you have the list items in your question?

Comment: I updated the question with all of the code of the NavigationDrawer.vue